# vmware/virtualbox 3d acceleration

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, hardware-acceleration

Can Ubuntu guests get 3d acceleration in vmware / virtual-box? I just want to enable desktop effects under virtualization, not 3D games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice tutorial for 3D acceleration in virtualbox [here](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2009/04/08/3d-acceleration-and-compiz-inside-virtualbox-guests/).